# Populating classes with many to many linq data

Tags: c#, linq, class, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many

Here is my c#

```
var result = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblItems)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblQuotes)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.tblSuppliers).GroupBy(tbl => new { tbl.tblQuotes, tbl.tblSuppliers, tbl.tblItems })
            .Select(grouped => new QuoteViewModel
            {
                Quote = new Quote { ID = grouped.Key.tblQuotes.ID,
                                    QuoteNo = grouped.Key.tblQuotes.QuoteNo ,
                                    Date = grouped.Key.tblQuotes.RequestDate},

                Supplier = new Supplier { ID = grouped.Key.tblSuppliers.ID,
                                          Name = grouped.Key.tblSuppliers.Supplier,
                                          TelNo = grouped.Key.tblSuppliers.Tel },

                Item = new Item { ID = grouped.Key.tblItems.ID,
                                  Name = grouped.Key.tblItems.Name,
                                  PartNo = grouped.Key.tblItems.PartNo },
                Quantity = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Quantity),
                Price = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Price)
            });

            AllQuotes AllQuotes = new AllQuotes();
            foreach (var quoteId in db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Select(qis => qis.QuoteID).Distinct())
            {
                int id = quoteId;
                foreach (var row in result.Where(row => row.Quote.ID == id))
                {
                    Request Req = new Request();
                    Req.Quote = new Quote { ID = row.Quote.ID,
                                    QuoteNo = row.Quote.QuoteNo,
                                    Date = row.Quote.Date };
                    // should this be another foreach loop to select all the suppliers for this quote?
                    Req.Suppliers = new Supplier { ID = row.Supplier.ID,
                                              Name = row.Supplier.Name,
                                              TelNo = row.Supplier.TelNo };
                    // again should this be another foreach loop to select all the items for this quote?
                    Req.Items = new Item { ID = row.Item.ID,
                                      Name = row.Item.Name,
                                      PartNo = row.Item.PartNo };
                    Req.Quantity = row.Quantity;
                    Req.Price = row.Price;
                    AllQuotes.Reqs.Add(Req);
                }
            }
```

here is my class:-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ITAPP.Models
{
    public class Quote
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuoteNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PartNo { get; set; }
    }
    public class Supplier
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TelNo { get; set; }
    }
    public class QuoteViewModel
    {
        public Quote Quote { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public Quote Quote { get; set; }
        public Item Items { get; set; }
        public Supplier Suppliers { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
    public class AllQuotes
    {
        public List<Request> Reqs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

im not sure im getting this right, infact i know im not.

I think i need a list for suppliers and a list for items in each request, then i do a foreach for each quote items and each quote suppliers to add the data to those lists? is that right?

basically i should have:-
Quote
x ammount of Quote items
x ammount of suppliers that quoted for each item and their prices

Hopefully the above is enough for people to understand what im trying to do?

Thanks

EDIT:Samples

Here is what i want the data to look like

```
IS0001 20/11/2013

           | HP DL360p  | Samsung 840 Pro 256GB | Total 
ITSupplier | 1132       | 477                   | 1609
ITComms    | 1160       | 510                   | 1670
ITSol      | 1135       | 160                   | 1295
```

Here is the table layout

```
tblQuotes
ID | QuoteNo | Date

tblItems
ID | Itemname | Part No

tblSuppliers
ID | SupplierName | TelNo

tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers
ID | QuoteID | ItemID | SupplierID | Quantity | Price
```

so each quote should show each suppliers prices for each item

Comment: Please explain, perhaps with a simple example, what you want the output of your query to be and what the input data looks like. It's hard to grasp how your database is designed just from the above code.

Comment: I've provided an answer, hopefully it's what you are after. It's a pretty complex scenario with lots of unknowns from an outside point of view.

Comment: Looks like you should group by QuoteID and within that group, group by ItemId. But the sample data doesn't help because it's not clear how it's related to your entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to do any grouping. If you need to break down everything in a table, then you need all of that granular data in your viewmodel. To add up the totals, just do this in your view.

So create your viewmodel (note: I'm not using your `QuoteViewModel` class at all. I'm using the `AllQuotes` class as your viewmodel) like this:

```
var viewmodel = new AllQuotes();

viewmodel.Reqs = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers
        .Include(tbl => tbl.tblItems)
        .Include(tbl => tbl.tblQuotes)
        .Include(tbl => tbl.tblSuppliers)
        .Select(tbl => new Request
        {
            Quote = new Quote { ID = tbl.tblQuotes.ID,
                                QuoteNo = tbl.tblQuotes.QuoteNo ,
                                Date = tbl.tblQuotes.RequestDate},

            Supplier = new Supplier { ID = tbl.tblSuppliers.ID,
                                      Name = tbl.tblSuppliers.Supplier,
                                      TelNo = tbl.tblSuppliers.Tel },

            Item = new Item { ID = tbl.tblItems.ID,
                              Name = tbl.tblItems.Name,
                              PartNo = tbl.tblItems.PartNo },
            Quantity = tbl.Quantity,
            Price = tbl.Price
        }).ToList();
```

Basically it's just a copy of your db table.

Then in your view, just create a table and do all the necessary grouping there. This creates a table per quote

E.g.

```
@foreach (var quote in Model.Reqs.GroupBy(r => r.Quote.ID).OrderBy(g => g.First().Quote.QuoteNo))
{
    <h3>@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo @quote.First().Quote.Date</h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><!--blank top-left cell--></th>
                @foreach (var item in quote.GroupBy(r => r.Item.ID).OrderBy(g => g.First().Item.Name))
                {
                    <th>@item.First().Item.Name</th>
                }
                <th>Total Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var supp in quote.GroupBy(r => r.Supplier.ID))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@supp.First().Supplier.Name</td>                            
                    @foreach (var item in supp.OrderBy(r => r.Item.Name))
                    {
                        <td>@item.Price</td>
                    }
                    <td>@supp.Sum(r => r.Price)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Please accept that this is all off the top of my head as I don't have an IDE or your db to hand, so there may be syntax errors. Hopefully it will get you going in the right direction.

#### edit

Also, note that I've made the assumption that all suppliers will have quoted for all items.

Comment: can you show me where i would add the foreach and groupby to display multiple quotes? THanks

Comment: just one error in it i dont know how to fix "CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." this is for the line " @foreach (var req in supp.SelectMany(r => r).OrderBy(r => r.Items.Name))"

Comment: Maybe try changing `var req` to `Request req`?

Comment: Can you paste the model declaration from your view please. Should be at the top of the `.cshtml` file...

Comment: its this @model IEnumerable<ITAPP.Models.AllQuotes>
@{

Comment: Try changing that to `@model ITAPP.Models.AllQuotes`

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back to me, the same error again im afarid

Comment: Hi there, do you have any update? anything i can test? what does the error mean? Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure without having your full setup in front of me. The only thing I can suggest is what's mentioned on MSDN: `This error occurs if you call a generic method without explicitly providing the type arguments and the compiler cannot infer which type arguments are intended. To avoid this error, add the intended type arguments in angle brackets.`. So try going through all the generic methods (`SelectMany`,`GroupBy`,`OrderBy` etc) and adding the type that should be be inferred. E.g.: `@foreach(var req in supp.SelectMany<Request>(r => r)`. Not sure what else to try, sorry.

Comment: ive added a bounty that i wish to give you when its working, as your help has been really good thus far

Comment: Hi have you seen the comments ive posted in the discussion thread for this? it doesnt quite work as expected yet

Comment: I've contributed to the chat - hadn't been getting any notifications

Comment: Hi There, i just wanted to add a where statment for to the query to get just one quote, but i dont know where to add the .Where statement, ive tried a few places but get errors, can you show me? Thanks

Comment: You could do it in a number of places but I'd do it before the `.Select(...)` statement. I.e. `(...include statements...).Where(...).Select(tbl => new Request`